# R: Function that executes script n times, printing only the last request

Tags: r, list, simulation, apply

Months ago, I was seraching and finding a function that could do the following things: 
From script A, it could execute script B n times. As a result, it would create a list with n elements and each list element would contain only the last-requested object of script B. For example, if the last line of script B contains a vector consisting of the means of some data, the list would contain only that vector. 
I can't seem to find this function any more.

Here is what I need to do: 
My script B contains of simulations and calculations performed on the simulated data. As a result, the script prints a matrix. I want to re-execute this script n times, resulting in a list with n elements, each containing a result matrix.

**A bonus** would be to be able to vary the seed in script B - that is, list[[1]] containing the data simulated with set.seed(1).

I know this problem begs for a function from the apply family - in the following example, source() was not accepted as a function.

```
listsmalln <- lapply(n, source("Small samples/scriptB.R"))
```

Hope this was understandable! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `lapply` with `replicate`. And make sure the last line of your script outputs the desired matrix, and is not a `print()` statement (`print()` outputs `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
lapply(1:n, function(x) source("test.R"))
```

The most easy way to change the seed is to create a function from the script with an input parameter with the seed.

Comment: I think that was the one I was looking for, thanks! Can you explain again what you mean by "create a function from the script with an input parameter with the seed"?

Comment: Look at the answer of Val, which explains how you could make a function of the script.

Answer (score -1):

If your script `B` could be a function which returns the matrix it's straightforward:

*Script B*: (as `functionB.R`):

```
functionB <-  function(x){

  set.seed(x)

  return matrix(runif(100),ncol=10)

}
```

*Script A:*

```
source('functionB.R')

lapply(1:10,function(x) functionB(x))
```